# Changing the height of iframe according to the content in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a popup div in which I have an iframe. Initially, I have set the height of iframe to some px according to the content in it.

Now, I have a click event on the iframe from which I am redirecting to another view but this view has more content to fit the height. So I want to change the height of the iframe on that event or on the load of other view but I am unable to access the iframe from within that click event of a button.

Comment: Is the page loaded in the iframe in your site or someone else's? Modern browsers make this somewhat impossible in the latter case.

Comment: It is in my site itself. Thanks for the concern.

Comment: Use `iframe-resizer`

Comment: @J.Kovacevic can't use it.. :)

Comment: May be this will help you [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471547/change-iframe-height-according-to-content)

Answer (score 0):

[EasyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) provides a bunch of useful functions in order to manipulate communication between the client and fetched iframes

[Here is an example](http://consumer.easyxdm.net/current/example/resize_iframe.html)  similar with what you want to achieve.
Keep in mind that you should also control the content into the iframe as well.